# C# получение данных из json

Tags: c#

Я C# вообще не знаю, но появилась задача из

```
 {"response":[2,5,6,7,12,20,21,22,23,34,37,42,45,46,54,57,59,61,133,169,173,175,180,182,187,190,193,194,198,199,201,230,231,234,237,254,277,287,288,316,326,334,341,345,358,366,369,373]}
```

Получить response

Решил по "Говнокодить" и решить задачу так

```
    var match = Regex.Match(users_id_list, @"{""response"":[(.*?)]}");
    var clear_id = match.Groups[1].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(clear_id);
```

Но ни чего не получается получить.
Где я ошибся ?

Comment: вы же пару дней назад задавали этот же вопрос, но пользовались в нем JSON.NET, который вполне нормально работает

Comment: Не работает потому что я не знаю какую библиотеку подключит

Comment: Используйте JSON.NET, который у вас был изначально. Он удобен и уж точно гораздо проще этих танцев с регулярками

Comment: Не обижайте регулярки! ╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: Как подключить библиотеку  JSON.NET

Comment: Решил не доставать Вас, не обижать регулярки и не мучить себя. Буду отсылать данные на свой сайт, а там json_decode мне поможет

Comment: @Vlmake JSON.NET как и любую другую библиотеку можно подключить через Nuget. 

@uzumaxy я их ни в коем случае не обижаю, но это явно не тот случай, где их стоит применять

Comment: Оке, тогда пойду поставлю стол на место

Comment: @uzumaxy так это был смайл?) Я было подумал, что регулярка))

Answer (score 1):

Готовый пример на C#: [скачать](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sw6h5xktygwm898/JSON_Parser.7z)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace JSON_Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{""response"":[2,5,6,7,12,20,21,22,23,34,37,42,45,46,54,57,59,61,133,169,173,175,180,182,187,190,193,194,198,199,201,230,231,234,237,254,277,287,288,316,326,334,341,345,358,366,369,373]}";
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (var item in obj["response"])
            {
                Console.Write(item + "; ");
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to exit... ");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "Newtonsoft" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)

Comment: Вы скопировали код с ответа или открыли созданный мною проект?

Comment: @Vlmake мой вам совет - потратьте полчаса-час времени на изучение основ работы с Visual Studio. Почитайте про подключение сборок к проекту и про использование NuGet - это самые азы, и если вы с ними не знакомы, то вам будет сложно понять и самому решить вашу задачу

Comment: У меня не консольное, а Windows Forms. Я пытаюсь Messagebox.show item , но не получается. Точнее пишется, что это не возможно

Comment: >У меня не консольное, а Windows Forms

Для работы с json абсолютно никакой разницы, какое это приложение. Просто вы почему-то упорно не желаете разобраться в том, что у вас не работает

Comment: http://s5.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/01/1a0945663cb2693861b12c246d004280.png

Comment: @Vlmake у вас ооочень большие пробелы в понимании основ самого языка. Вы же пытаетесь вместо строки засунуть в MessageBox JToken. Разумеется, без явного приведения это не будет работать. Ваша проблема совсем не сложна, но  вы к сожалению плохо знакомы с самим языком, благодаря чему трудности у вас появляются буквально на пустом месте. Приведите этот item к строке, посмотрите в отладчике, что именно вам нужно из него выводить